# Get version of .app inside .pkg without extracting (MacOS, NodeJS)?

Tags: node.js, macos, pkg-file

Is it possible to get version of .app inside .pkg without extracting on MacOS using NodeJS?

Is it possible to do so using other programming languages on other OS. For example, if I copy .pkg file to Windows can I still obtain version of .app inside somehow?